# event.getAction() misses out on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android-view

I have an app that draws a grid of dots (let's say 3x3). The user is asked to draw something on that grid. If the user's finger touches one of the dots in the grid, this dot is being colored. In addition a line will be drawn between each two touched dots.

The issue - event.getAction() will often miss out on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. What do I mean? - well, let's say the user drew a straight line connecting three dots. Often the first dot will be colored, the third (last) dot will be colored but the second (middle) dot will not get colored.

So I logged what `else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)` is doing and found out that often `event.getAction()` will not "notice" the change in finger location on the screen.

I noticed that if I pass my finger SLOWER along the imaginary path I want to draw, `event.getAction()` better notices the finger movements.

**After some testing I've also noticed that as I draw more and more lines on the screen, the game becomes increasingly slower/sluggish. It seems like that app is collecting so much data (event data?) that it doesn't manage to process it in a timely manner (I get the log: I/Choreographer: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread). Could this be an issue of an over-sized cache of some sort? How can I clean that "cache" once I know the user's action is done?**

Does anyone have experience with such a case where the system will not track finger movements fast enough?

============ FURTHER EXPERIMENTATION ==========================

After reading what @Jimpanzee wrote I delved more into the documentation: I read about using getHistoricalX(int, int) and getHistoricalY(int, int). As it seems Android batches motion events so getX & getY might deliver only the LAST event in that batch. This can be a problem if you have fast movements on the screen. So I turned to use getHistoricalX and getHistoricalY in addition to getX and getY. This for some strange reason didn't solve the problem: I still get dots that are being touched but not getting colored.

An example can be seen below:

[image: Showing two lines - one is missing a dot. Both lines were drawn from top to bottom, the left one was drawn first]

I am using an ArrayList>
Each ArrayList defines a path made out of dots by the order they were touched.
an ArrayList holds all thos paths

1. The grid is numbered 0, 100, 200, 300, 400 on each the X and Y axis
2. The first dot to be fainted was [100, 100] - the finger went all the way down, painting four dots, last dot being [100, 400].
3. the second line was also drawn from top to bottom but you can see that the third dot from the top [200, 300] is missing.

I couldn't explain that so I logged the touch events:

1. moveH means action MOVE + historical data
2. moveC means action MOVE + current data
3. When a touched point was close to a dot on the grid [add point] is noted
4. From time to time the whole array of paths is printed out

**If you look at the log, you will see that after adding point [200, 200] the Y values get strange - they jump from 212.53839 (in the last seen historical point) to 412.45544 and stays high all the way until the next dot is added to the array. That explains why dot [200, 300] was left out and never drawn.**

```
383:  Action moveH x: 198.75 y: 284.8833
383:  Action moveH x: 199.6875 y: 305.07257
387:  Action moveH x: 204.84375 y: 326.94427
387:  Action moveH x: 196.875 y: 212.53839
387:  Action moveH [add point] x: 200 y: 200
387:  [[Point(100, 100), Point(100, 200), Point(100, 300), Point(100, 400)], [Point(200, 100), Point(200, 200)]]
504:  Action moveE x: 210.0 y: 412.45544
504:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
504:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
504:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
504:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
504:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
504:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
508:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
508:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
508:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
508:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
508:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
508:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
508:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
508:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
508:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
508:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
508:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
508:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
508:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
512:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
512:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
512:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
512:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
512:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
512:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
512:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
512:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
515:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
515:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
515:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
515:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
515:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
515:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
515:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
515:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
515:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
515:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
515:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
515:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
519:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
519:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
519:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
519:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
519:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
519:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
519:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
519:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
519:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
523:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
523:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
523:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
527:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
527:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
527:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
527:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
527:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
527:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
527:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
527:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
527:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
527:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
531:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
531:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
531:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
531:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
531:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
531:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
531:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
531:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
531:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
531:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
531:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
531:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
531:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
531:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
531:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
531:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
531:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
535:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
535:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
535:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
535:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
535:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
535:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
535:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
535:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
535:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
535:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
535:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
535:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
535:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
535:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
539:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
539:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
539:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
539:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
539:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
539:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
539:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
539:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
539:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
539:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
539:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
539:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
539:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
539:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
539:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
543:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
543:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
543:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
543:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
543:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
543:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
543:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
543:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
543:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
543:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
543:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
547:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
547:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
547:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
547:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
547:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
547:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
547:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
547:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
547:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
547:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
547:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
547:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
547:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
547:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
547:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
547:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
547:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
547:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
551:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
551:  Action moveH x: 205.78125 y: 345.4511
551:  Action moveH x: 207.1875 y: 362.2755
551:  Action moveH x: 207.65625 y: 369.00528
551:  Action moveH x: 208.125 y: 378.2587
551:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 397.60675
551:  Action moveH x: 209.53125 y: 400.97162
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 404.3365
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 407.7014
551:  Action moveH x: 210.0 y: 411.90747
551:  Action moveC [add point] x: 200 y: 400
551:  [[Point(100, 100), Point(100, 200), Point(100, 300), Point(100, 400)], [Point(200, 100), Point(200, 200), Point(200, 400)]]
719:  Action moveE x: 210.0 y: 424.52576
719:  Action moveH x: 210.46875 y: 415.27234
719:  Action moveH x: 210.46875 y: 418.63724
719:  Action moveH x: 210.46875 y: 421.1609
```

This is my doDraw (like onDraw):

```
    public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    PathPoint xya = null;       

    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
        {
            int xPos = j * mNodeGap;
            int yPos = i * mNodeGap;

            try {
                xya = new PathPoint(xPos, yPos, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               

            mNodeCoordinates[i][j] = xya;

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, xPos, yPos, null);
        }
    }

    synchronized (mViewThread.getSurefaceHolder()) 
    {
        //draw path
        for (Path path : mGraphics)
        {           
            float aStartCoordinates[] = {0f, 0f};
            float aEndCoordinates[] = {0f, 0f};

            //get path values       
            PathMeasure pm = new PathMeasure(path, true);

            pm.getPosTan(0f, aStartCoordinates, null);  
            //System.out.println("aStartCoordinates X:" + aStartCoordinates[0] + " aStartCoordinates Y:" + aStartCoordinates[1]);
            pm.getPosTan(pm.getLength(), aEndCoordinates, null);
            //System.out.println("aEndCoordinates X:" + aEndCoordinates[0] + " aEndCoordinates Y:" + aEndCoordinates[1]);

            //coordinates are within game board boundaries
            if((aStartCoordinates[0] >= 1  && aStartCoordinates[1] >= 1) && (aEndCoordinates[0] >= 1 && aEndCoordinates[1] >= 1))
            {
                canvas.drawPath(path, mPathPaint);
            }                   
        }

        for (ArrayList<PathPoint> nodePattern : mNodesHitPatterns) 
        {
            for (PathPoint nodeHit : nodePattern) 
            {
                canvas.drawBitmap(mDotOK, nodeHit.x - ((mDotOK.getWidth()/2) - (mBitmap.getWidth()/2)), nodeHit.y - ((mDotOK.getHeight()/2) - (mBitmap.getHeight()/2)), null);
            }               
        }           
    }
}
```

And the onTouchEvent:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {            

    synchronized (mViewThread.getSurefaceHolder()) {

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            System.out.println("Action downE x: " + event.getX() + " y: " + event.getY());

            for (int i = 0; i < mGridSize; i++) 
            {                   
                for (int j = 0; j < mGridSize; j++) 
                {
                    PathPoint pathPoint = mNodeCoordinates[i][j];

                    if((Math.abs((int)event.getX() - pathPoint.x) <= 35) && (Math.abs((int)event.getY() - pathPoint.y) <= 35))
                    {
                        //mPath.moveTo(pathPoint.x + mBitmap.getWidth() / 2, pathPoint.y + mBitmap.getHeight() / 2);

                        //System.out.println("Action down x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);
                        ArrayList<PathPoint> newNodesPattern = new ArrayList<PathPoint>();
                        mNodesHitPatterns.add(newNodesPattern);
                        //mNodesHitPatterns.add(nh);
                        //                          pathPoint.setAction("down");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }                   
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            final int historySize = event.getHistorySize();

            System.out.println("Action moveE x: " + event.getX() + " y: " + event.getY());

            coordinateFound:
                for (int i = 0; i < mGridSize; i++) 
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mGridSize; j++) 
                    {
                        PathPoint pathPoint = mNodeCoordinates[i][j];   

                        if((Math.abs((int)event.getX() - pathPoint.x) <= 35) && (Math.abs((int)event.getY() - pathPoint.y) <= 35))
                        {                               
                            int lastPatternIndex = mNodesHitPatterns.size()-1;                  
                            ArrayList<PathPoint> lastPattern = mNodesHitPatterns.get(lastPatternIndex);
                            int lastPatternLastNode = lastPattern.size()-1;                             

                            if(lastPatternLastNode != -1)
                            {
                                if(!pathPoint.equals(lastPattern.get(lastPatternLastNode).x, lastPattern.get(lastPatternLastNode).y))
                                {
                                    lastPattern.add(pathPoint);     
                                    System.out.println("Action moveC [add point] x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                lastPattern.add(pathPoint);
                                System.out.println("Action moveC [add point] x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);
                            }                                           

                            break coordinateFound;
                        }
                        else //no current match => try historical
                        {
                            if(historySize > 0)
                            {
                                for (int k = 0; k < historySize; k++)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Action moveH x: " + event.getHistoricalX(k) + " y: " + event.getHistoricalY(k));
                                    if((Math.abs((int)event.getHistoricalX(k) - pathPoint.x) <= 35) && (Math.abs((int)event.getHistoricalY(k) - pathPoint.y) <= 35))
                                    {                                                   
                                        int lastPatternIndex = mNodesHitPatterns.size()-1;                  
                                        ArrayList<PathPoint> lastPattern = mNodesHitPatterns.get(lastPatternIndex);
                                        int lastPatternLastNode = lastPattern.size()-1;                             

                                        if(lastPatternLastNode != -1)
                                        {
                                            if(!pathPoint.equals(lastPattern.get(lastPatternLastNode).x, lastPattern.get(lastPatternLastNode).y))
                                            {
                                                lastPattern.add(pathPoint);
                                                System.out.println("Action moveH [add point] x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            lastPattern.add(pathPoint);
                                            System.out.println("Action moveH [add point] x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);
                                        }                                           

                                        break coordinateFound;
                                    }
                                }
                            }                               
                        }
                    }
                }       
        }
        else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mGridSize; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < mGridSize; j++) {

                    PathPoint pathPoint = mNodeCoordinates[i][j];

                    if((Math.abs((int)event.getX() - pathPoint.x) <= 35) && (Math.abs((int)event.getY() - pathPoint.y) <= 35))
                    {
                        //the location of the node                      
                        //mPath.lineTo(pathPoint.x + mBitmap.getWidth() / 2, pathPoint.y + mBitmap.getHeight() / 2);

                        //System.out.println("Action up x: " + pathPoint.x + " y: " + pathPoint.y);

                        //mGraphics.add(mPath);
                        //                          mNodesHit.add(pathPoint);
                        //                          pathPoint.setAction("up");
                        break;
                    }                       
                }
            }               
        }

        System.out.println(mNodesHitPatterns.toString());

        //create mPath
        for (ArrayList<PathPoint> nodePattern : mNodesHitPatterns) 
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < nodePattern.size(); i++) 
            {
                if(i == 0) //first node in pattern
                {
                    mPath.moveTo(nodePattern.get(i).x + mBitmap.getWidth() / 2, nodePattern.get(i).y + mBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    mPath.lineTo(nodePattern.get(i).x + mBitmap.getWidth() / 2, nodePattern.get(i).y + mBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
                }

                mGraphics.add(mPath);
            }                               
        }

        return true;
    }  
}
```

============ FURTHER INFORMATION ==========================

The questions is- why does the device behaves like that?

Grateful for any input on this,
D.

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I am using the Samsung/Google Nexus S

Comment: Have you tried using `getActionMasked()` instead of `getAction()`?

Comment: @Jimpanzee could you elaborate on why this might help me? I don't seem to get it (after taking a look at the documentation)

Comment: The variable sometimes holds data not just about the action but also about the pointer index. `getActionMasked()` gives you the action only. Have you tried it? It may not help but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: When you move your finger, is the touch event not being recognised at all or is it just not being classified as `ACTION_MOVE`?

Comment: @Jimpanzee what you raise is an interesting point - however, I am using a single finger so which pointer was used is not an issue. As it seems, the event is BEING classified as MOVE event BUT for some reason I get what seems to be bad Y values. Please look at the added information I gave in my post - maybe it will give you more ideas. Thanks for your effort! :)

Comment: Your LogCat output is showing a repeating sequence every 9 lines... strange!

Comment: @Jimpanzee - correct, didn't notice this. It could be due to an artifact caused by a loop I am using. I am checking to see the meaning of this.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial regarding sigle touch: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTouch/article.html
You can implement it and run it to assure that you hardware is working.
The problem might be the way you evaluate event.getAction() 
Also when you override  boolean onTouch return tru if you consumed the event.